# Java how to discovery WCF service?

Tags: c#, java, wcf, web-services, ws-discovery

Please visit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31285/WS-Discovery-for-WCF,I have download the source code and written a WCF service in .NET Framework 3.5 using the related WSDiscovery, and published this service to the web page with the same configuration in the source code.
  It runs correct, WCF client can discovery this service too.Now my problem comes, Can Java client discovery this service by WS-Discovery or others? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First thing that google returned was [java-ws-autodiscovery](http://code.google.com/p/java-ws-discovery/). There is an 'axis' framework used by java people and I think it includes much of the  WS* interoperability. It should be supported from what I can see. Never used them just read up on them.

Comment: Thanks,I have already read this article, it can't help me.I have used WSDiscoveryFinder and WSDiscoveryServer class,it failed. What I need is just using Java code to discovery the services,but not using Java to write webservice.As I'm a newer to webservice,could you give me some ideas or some useful links to implement it?I have read a couple of articles, but any of them works well.

Comment: WS* is a newer standard in Web Security and should be provided by all major providers. Have you looked into the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Axis documentation?

Comment: Looks like an update to Axis2 here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Axis2 and one more http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/28816 . It seems like there is support for your wcf service to be consumed by java.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of CXF have support for WS-Discovery.  See:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-discovery.html

and

http://www.dankulp.com/blog/2013/05/apache-cxf-and-ws-discovery/

Comment: Actually, I have tried this simply by the sample code . It can't discovery the WebService written by C# and published to the webpage by IIS,I'm thinking that whether the important is the interoperability between java and C# or it can't do that.But I recognize that the ws-discovery is a well-formed protocol,and it will be known both in java and C#,I want know the theory,but it is hard to start.